# ScrollView delegate not called inside custom tableviewCell class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

1. I'm using `UITableViewCell` custom class
2. Using `Scrollview` for horizontal scroll inside the `tableviewcell`
3. Write `Tableview` delegates in `UIViewcontroller`
4. Writing `scrollview` delegate in `UITableview` cell class
5. Delegate method not called.

My Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var matchesTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    matchesTableView.delegate = self
    matchesTableView.dataSource = self
    tableViewSetup()

}

func tableViewSetup() {
            matchesTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
            matchesTableView.estimatedRowHeight = self.view.bounds.height
    matchesTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    matchesTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
}

}

// MARK: UITableviewdelegate

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return self.view.bounds.height
}
}

UITableView Cell:

import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var bannerScrollView: UIScrollView!

  @IBOutlet weak var matchesPageControl: UIPageControl!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code+
    self.bannerScrollView.delegate = self

}
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    matchesPageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: It looks ok, are you sure the scroll view is actually being scrolled? Just log the scroll contentOffset. Maybe the touches are being absorbed by something in the tableView cell. TBH putting a scrollview inside a cell looks strange. I wonder if there's another way.

Comment: Tableview scroll is working fine and also scrollview scroll perfectly. My issue is scrollview delegate not called. so that i can not use the page control. Thanks!

Comment: Add this method --  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    matchesPageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}      in your ViewController class and check if it gets called. If yes that's because UITableViewDelegate inturns conform to UIScrollViewDelegate.

Comment: @Help Thanks a lot..! you saved my day. Working fine.

Comment: @SASIKUMAR happy to help